# javax.servlet.ServletException: Class [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer] is not a Servlet

Tags: tomcat, jersey, tomcat9, jersey-3.0

You may feel this is a duplicated question, but none of the questions with the same title solve my problems. I am using Jersey 3.0 creating a RESTful web service in Eclipse, I use Tomcat 9.0 as my server.

Answer (score 3):

Jersey 3.x uses [Servlet 5.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/), which now uses the Jakarta naming. All the `javax.servlet` packaging has now changed to `jakarta.servlet`. The Jersey [`ServletContainer`](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/3.0.0/containers/jersey-servlet-core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.java)  now extends `jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet`; it is not `javax` anymore. The first Tomcat to use Jakarta is Tomcat 10.x; Tomcat 9.x still uses the `javax.servlet` packaging. So if you want to use Jersey 3.x, then you should upgrade your Tomcat to [10.x](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi).